# DllImport vs LoadLibrary, What is the best way?

Tags: c#, winapi, dllimport, loadlibrary

i'm usually using Win32 API in c#.NET. But not declare all in one application. Sometimes usually using user32, sometimes gdi32 ... 
I think when i declare all api function, those use lot of memory. 
What is the best way using API in .NET ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the Win32 API is available through managed abstractions. Otherwise, declare the ones you need using `DllImport`.

`LoadLibrary` should really only be used where you have provided alternate functionality, that is, your application can work even without that particular API function. If the API function is critical, using `DllImport` will let the loader worry about whether the function exists or not.

Answer (score 9):

LoadLibrary is useful when you are writing code that might be used in an environment that may or may not have the desired dll -- for example, you might have a program that can use a special crypto dll if it is available, but can still operate without it.  Using DllImport would require that dll to exist.

Comment: This is generally the time I end up using LoadLibrary.

Comment: LoadLibrary is also usefull for loading plugins